# how to remove single quotes and comma in single trim function in php

Tags: php

I need to remove single quotes and comma in single `trim()` function in PHP.
For example see the below code:

```
$Myvariable1 = rtrim($Myvariable,"'");
rtrim($Myvariable1,",");
```

The first line I am using "`rtrim`" to remove the single quote and in the second line again i am using "rtrim" to remove the comma.

Can we use the single trim function to remove both the single quote and comma?

Comment: 5 seconds on the rtrim manual page would answer this

Comment: You should really [read the docs](http://php.net/rtrim). It literally shows you code examples on how to trim multiple characters.

Comment: **character_mask

    You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.**

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your reply

Comment: I tried "string rtrim ( string $str [, string $character_mask ] )" but i am not getting the correct output. I need output like 'Hong Kong','Indonesia','India','Singapore' instead of 'Hong Kong','Indonesia','India','Singapore',''. Can any one help me?

Comment: why only trim function? I think you could do this by several other methods, please add more details to your question.

Answer (score -2):

Not the answer you were looking for with rtrim, but achieves the same thing.

```
str_replace("'",'',str_replace(',','',$string));
```